# How to show AlertBox from DataTableSource when onSubmitted is triggered in the TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on the project where I am using PaginatedDataTable. I am using Textfields in the cells. Now what I want is that if I write anything in the textfield and if it is incorrect, then I wanted to show an AlertDialog. As I am using DataTableSource therefore I do not know how to do that.

```
class TextDataTable extends DataTableSource {

  List<TextEditingController> firstController = [];
  List<TextEditingController> secondController = [];

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {

    firstController.add(TextEditingController());
    secondController.add(TextEditingController());

    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(
        TextField(
          controller: firstController[index],
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            if (value.isNotEmpty && value == data[index]["column1"].toString()) {
              //here I wanted to show dialogBox
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      DataCell(
        TextField(
          controller: secondController[index],
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            if (value.isNotEmpty && value == data[index]["column2"].toString()) {
              //here I wanted to show dialogBox
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement isRowCountApproximate
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  // TODO: implement rowCount
  int get rowCount => data.length;

  @override
  // TODO: implement selectedRowCount
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated? Thanks.